# Creating Powershell Script to Have ALT, and Windows Key become Control Key

Tags: windows, powershell

Im trying to create my first Powershell script, Im a Linux guy so I normally user Terminal. What I want to do is run a script everytime I turn on my computer where The Alt Key and Windows Key runs the Control Key function.

I want to do this for easier and faster Copy and paste.

Can someone assist in helping develop a script.

I believe something like this would work:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'alt' { Invoke-Item CONTROL Key Function Command Here }
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'win' { Invoke-Item CONTROL Key Function Command Here }
```

Comment: There may be a tool that will already do this. Have you investigated Microsoft PowerToys? https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys